# VB.NET hwnd hide statusbar

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I need to hide the statusbar on an external application.

Can someone explain me how to hide "msctls_statusbar32".

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found an way to do this:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
   Public Shared Function FindWindowEx(parentHandle As IntPtr, childAfter As IntPtr, className As String, windowTitle As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function GetWindow(parentHandle As IntPtr, childAfter As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function ShowWindow(parentHandle As IntPtr, childAfter As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function


   Dim statusBarHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(_hwndX, IntPtr.Zero, "msctls_statusbar32", IntPtr.Zero)
   Dim Ichildwind As IntPtr = GetWindow(statusBarHandle, 5)
   ShowWindow(statusBarHandle, Nothing)
```